# Jest Unexpected identifier: React

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

When I try to execute a test on reactjs with jest, it always return me the error: 
[image]
I have correctly install Jest, I have try to remove import but it do an error with the next.

App.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow }from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.js';
import User from './Modules/User.js';

const user = {
    email: "test@gmail.com",
    first_name: "test",
    last_name: "test"
}

test('Users renders properly', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow("<User users={user}/>");
  const element = wrapper.find('input');
});
```

If it doesn't say error for import, it don't recognise shallow when I set shallow();

Feel free to ask for more detail.

Comment: Have you configured `react` with `enzyme`?

Comment: No, where and how can I do that ?

Comment: I have rechecked and it seems like some babel modules are missing:
Please check if you have: `babel-preset-env`, `babel-preset-es2015`, `babel-jest` `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`.

Comment: I have just not need to use jest for my test, is use `react-scripts test --env=jsdom` and it works perfect, with little modifications, thanks to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change `jest` to `react-scripts test --env=jsdom` in `npm test`