# Error in a basic Jest unit test - Unexpected identifier | _Object$defineProperty | babel-runtime

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm writing a simple unit test using enzyme and Jest.
but I'm having an issue with a basic initial test.
as you can see in the screen,

the one who is failing is just the "renders without crashing" test.

[image]

I have tried to use:

- "***exclude***": "/node_modules/" in tsconfig
- "***testPathIgnorePatterns*** | ***transformIgnorePatterns***" : "/node_modules/" in jest.config
- ***react-scripts test --env=jsdom*** like it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261252/jest-unexpected-identifier-react)

but it doesn't work.

please help!

my package.json

```
{
 "name": "my-app",
 "version": "0.12.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "@types/jest": "23.3.13",
   "@types/lodash": "^4.14.120",
   "@types/node": "10.12.18",
   "@types/react": "16.7.20",
   "@types/react-dom": "16.0.11",
   "@types/react-helmet": "^5.0.8",
   "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.1",
   "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.3",
   "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.12",
   "axios": "^0.18.0",
   "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
   "clipboard-polyfill": "^2.7.0",
   "core-js": "^2.6.5",
   "fscreen": "^1.0.2",
   "i18next": "^14.0.1",
   "moment": "^2.24.0",
   "normalizr": "^3.3.0",
   "polished": "^3.0.0",
   "react": "^16.7.0",
   "react-app-polyfill": "^0.2.2",
   "react-cookie": "^3.0.8",
   "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
   "react-dropzone": "^8.2.0",
   "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
   "react-i18next": "^9.0.8",
   "react-media": "^1.9.2",
   "react-pose": "^4.0.8",
   "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
   "react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
   "react-slick": "^0.24.0",
   "redux": "^4.0.1",
   "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.7",
   "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
   "reselect": "^4.0.0",
   "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
   "tech-vnc": "<url-to->/tech-vnc.git",
   "tech-websocket-renderer": "<url-to->/tech-websocket-renderer.git",
   "testbirds-styleguide": "<url-to->/testbirds-styleguide.git",
   "typescript": "3.2.4",
   "url-search-params-polyfill": "^5.0.0"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "prebuild": "npm run import-translations",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "build:nest": "env-cmd .env.nest npm run build",
   "import-translations": "node ./scripts/translations.js",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
 },
 "browserslist": [
   ">0.2%",
   "not dead",
   "not ie <= 11",
   "not op_mini all"
 ],
 "devDependencies": {
   "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
   "cross-fetch": "^3.0.0",
   "env-cmd": "^8.0.2",
   "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
   "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
   "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
   "moxios": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "build"
   ]
 }
```

my tsconfig.json

[image]

Comment: Did you configure Adapter in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

As of Enzyme 3, you will need to install Enzyme along with an Adapter corresponding to the version of React you are using.

The adapter will also need to be configured in your [global setup file](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#initializing-test-environment):

```
        import { configure } from 'enzyme';
        import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

        configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

For more help please check [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests).

And make sure you have added `node_modules` in exclude `tsconfig.json`.

In my cases I have added following,

```
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build",
        "scripts",
        "acceptance-tests",
        "webpack",
        "jest"
    ],
```

For example to check [here](https://github.com/santoshshinde2012/react-typescript-flight-search/blob/master/tsconfig.json).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I already have it in my setupTests.js file :-(
the error does not come from that unfortunately

Comment: can you please add your package.json file

Comment: Did you added babel.config.js and jest.config.js ?

Comment: I added my package.json and tsconfig.json.
I don't have js.config file anymore because I was getting the error with and without it.

many thanks

Comment: Can you please try with https://github.com/santoshshinde2012/react-typescript-flight-search/blob/master/tsconfig.json this config ?

Comment: And in you test code please check, you are importing App from '.'  may be u need to import from './App'